# how to use thymeleaf replace text in html

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

how to use thymeleaf replace text in html

i have tried

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home" th:text="${menuItem.name}" ></i>  <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

then get result

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home">Menu</i>  <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

i want get result like:

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> [[${menuItem.name}]] <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```

or

```
<a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span th:text="${menuItem.name}" th:remove="tag"> Menu Item</span> <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
```